# This page isn’t working. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: drupal, apache2, php-5.6

Website hosted in google cloud 
My website https://www.smcin.com/ made in drupal 7 not open. Give

> "This page isn’t working. www.smcin.com didn’t send any
>   data.ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

error. No idea happen. No error show in log. 
But backend is open properly.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file(s) and is it supported?

Comment: Can you say how you resolved the problem?